# Asp .Net Core hide menu on layout on database check

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-2.2

I need to hide and show some links in a sidebar menu according to a database check but since layout has no page model, how can i achieve this? It's easy if it's done with claims but i need to hit the database

```
@if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{
    <li class="nav-item has-treeview">

        <a asp-page="/Account/Documentos/Index" class="nav-link custom-sidebar-link">
            <i class="nav-icon fas fa-file-alt"></i>
            <p class="text-white">
                Documentos
            </p>
        </a>

    </li>
    // need to hide this on database check
    <li class="nav-item has-treeview">

        <a asp-page="/Account/Consumos/Index" class="nav-link custom-sidebar-link">
            <i class="nav-icon fas fa-cogs"></i>
            <p class="text-white">
                Arranque Produção
            </p>
        </a>

    </li>
}
```

Comment: You can use `Dependency Injection`, which will allow you to inject a class to your view, your class may contain a DBContext and you can do DB operators in that class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're trying to do DB operations in a layout (which doesn't contain a model), [Dependency Injection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-2.2) can help you.

You can define a class that have methods with DB access, register it to your services, and use it's methods easily from any View/Controller/pageModel

I'll explain with a code:

Here's our dependency:

```
public class MyDependency 
{
    // You can use dependency injection in a chained fashion, 
    // DBContext is injected in our dependency
    private readonly DBContext _dbContext;

    public MyDependency(DBContext dbContext)
    {
        _dbContext = dbContext;
    }

    // Define a method that access DB using dbContext
    public bool CheckInDb()
    {
        return dbContext.SomeCheck();
    }
}
```

Register it to your services in your `Startup` (Your dependency should be registered after DBContext has been registered)

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // Some code here

    services.AddDbContext<DBContext>(options =>
        options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

    services.AddScoped<MyDependency>();
}
```

Then in your layout:

```
@inject MyDependency MyDependency

@if(MyDependency.CheckInDb())
{
    // Do something
} 
else
{
    // Do something else
}
```

Comment: Thanks this is exactly what i needed, but i found out about viewcomponents that can have logic on them and they might be better if i just need to separate the logic

Comment: @Jackal I didn't know about `ViewComponent`s before your comment, seems like it's better than using `DI` in such situations, thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 1):

You can use viewmodel or HttpContext